Charging and Discharging a Powerbank through the same USB C Port
I am currently designing a PCB that has a vertical USB C plug on it which is used to plug a normal USB C powerbank into it. This is used to supply power to the PCB via USB Power Delivery. Not a problem right. Just need a PD controller IC. But now I also want to be able to charge the powerbank without unplugging it - through another USB C port on my PCB. Is this even possible?
In my understanding, since the powerbank obviously has its own PD controller to negotiate charging voltage, I'd somehow have to switch the CC lines between the charging USB C port on the PCB and the PD controller on the PCB, depending on wether I want to charge or discharge the powerbank.

Would this module solve your problem? https://www.amazon.com/Teyleten-Robot-Bidirectional-Buck-Boost-High-Power/dp/B0B7RT7CF4

Unfortunately, no. This is not the problem I am trying to solve. I want to use an of the shelve battery pack with a USB-C port not a custom lipo battery.
